# Is it possible to check via a script whether a Vagrant box is out of date?

Tags: windows, macos, scripting, vagrant

My team is using Vagrant and whenever a new box comes out we want to update to maintain up-to-date-ness. We are not concerned with a new version of a box being a problem.

Therefore I'm looking to create a script (on both Windows and Mac, yeah it will probably be different formats but the idea remains the same) that will check for updates and apply them if they exist.

What I mean is I want something for my team to run such as `vagrant_launch.sh` that will do

```
if box is out of date:
    update the box
vagrant up
```

Is the `if box is out of date:` portion of this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can run `vagrant box outdated` on a specific Vagrantfile to check if this particular is outdated or not.

You can also run `vagrant box outdated --global` to check for all boxes you have installed, for example

```
fhenri@machine:~$ vagrant box outdated --global
* 'windows_ie' wasn't added from a catalog, no version information
* 'ubuntu/trusty64' is outdated! Current: 20151117.0.0. Latest: 20151201.0.0
* 'ubuntu-12.04' wasn't added from a catalog, no version information
* 'puphpet/centos65-x64' is outdated! Current: 2.0. Latest: 20151130
* 'hashicorp/boot2docker' (v1.7.8) is up to date
* 'centos65' wasn't added from a catalog, no version information
* 'boxcutter/ubuntu1504' is outdated! Current: 2.0.9. Latest: 2.0.10
* 'aribabox' wasn't added from a catalog, no version information
```

You can check from Vagrant source but basically, if the box has metadata information, it will check from atlas (box repo) and fetch the metadata from the latest box with this name and compare the 2 metadata.

Comment: I know that's possible, but is it possible to translate this into any kind of if statement in bash for example?